# Download posts related with algorithms from Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, downloads

I have been using stackoverflow.com for the past month and have been reading posts about programming and algorithms daily. Can I download all the good posts (marked as community wiki perhaps) related the algorithms topics? Is there a way to do it?

Or if someone has done it and could share it as a PDF file please. In college I have Internet access, but at home I don't. So it will be very useful to me (and perhaps many others).

I just read a few similar posts here on Meta Stack Overflow .. It talks about some data dump download. But I don't get it.

Comment: What don't you get about the data dump?  What it is?  Where to get it?  How to use it?

Comment: I read that data is in GBs , but I only want good questions. and don't want to download GBs of data.

Comment: If you can point me to easy procedure , that would be very nice...

Comment: Okay.. I can grab these link I got. But are these the only community wiki marked posts .. only 219???

Comment: By the way thanks... I am having a database systems course this semester... and I am beginning to appreciate the course just now seeing this ... :)

Comment: Thanks... I replaced algorithm tag with programming, datastructure ... and got sufficient posts to spend my holidays.... I am writing %C% , it is saying 0 results.. why?

Comment: @rene I created another query with score > 0 and that gave me plenty of good stuff... Together with yours, My problem is solved :)..

Comment: I mean score > 10 ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want for 99% by using The [StackExchangeDataExplorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) (or SEDE). The SEDE enables you to run sql queries against a couple of the most important tables from the SE network. This data is refreshed once a week (on Monday 03:00 UTC if I'm correct)

I have so far two queries for you:

[Posts that have a tag `algorithm` and are communitiy wiki](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/163999/algorithm-cw-posts)

and

[Posts that have the tag `c` and are community wiki](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/164017/post-with-tags-c)

Notice that [SEDE comes with a help](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq)  and here on meta [a datadictionary is hopefully  kept up to date](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100)

If you want ALL data of ALL sites you could [download/torrent the full datadump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-cc-data-now-hosted-by-the-internet-archive/) but you have provide your own dbms-engine, cpu power and storage to make that fly.